# Why are there cracks all over my upper floor ceilings and walls?

Tags: drywall, attic, structural, cracks

We bought a townhome in 2012 and we moved in. The walls were OK, no cracks except an oblique one near the vent in the bedroom. In the summer of 2014 the association decided to replace the roof. After that we started having some cracks which we thought were due to the roof that was changed. We decided to fix them ourselves and started working on them in the winter of 2014. By March some of them cracked again on the same spot. We contacted the association to send someone to take a look because we wanted to make sure there is not a structural problem before we fix everything. It took all 2015 to convince them to send someone and in the spring of 2016 they finally sent an engineer who took forever to create the report and the report said we have truss uplift. At this point the whole house had cracks, in the master bedroom I could see every sheet of drywall where it separated from the others.The association just installed some baffles in the attic and sent a company to fix the walls in October 2016. Now we have new cracks and they say they talked to some contractors and is due to humidity and they won't do anything.They completely dismissed the engineer's report although they choose the engineer.  Does anyone have any idea what is going on? 
I attached some pictures.[image][image][image]
Update: The pictures are no1: wall-ceiling joint in the bathroom, no2 :wall-wall joint in the master bedroom closet and no3 is below a window in the second bedroom.
Update 2: From what I know we used to have mushroom vents and they changed them for ridge vents.

Comment: Go around the place checking window frames/sills and door frames with a level (check the horizontal and the vertical), and also...are any doors and/or windows hard to open and close?

Comment: It's really difficult to answer a question like this through the internet, especially since the photos have no context.  If an engineer came to the site and did a thorough inspection, I'd be inclined to believe whatever they put in the report. Changes in humidity/temperature in the area above the ceiling, could surely cause movement in materials.

Comment: Your question invites even more questions: were gutters relocated? Removed? What was the roof replaced with? What roofing materials was removed? What else did the engineer look at? Soils rich in expanding clays are notorious for causing cracks in building structures especially if local drainage has been modified by, say, removing roof gutters, but without the soil testing results (generated by the engineering lab prior to construction) it's impossible to say.

Comment: Truss uplift would account for cracks at the wall-ceiling joint, primarily. What we see here seems to indicate either extreme seasonal humidity/temp variation or foundation movement. I agree that it's not a question for the internet, though.

Comment: The engineer looked at the foundation also, and inspected the other 3 units in the building. None had our issues, and foundation is fine. I know they changed the type of ventilation , I think we had a mushroom ?  and they installed some new type that theoretically is better. The rest of the roof was the same, they just replaced the shingles. The weird thing is everything started after they changed the roof, we had no cracks before that. Also the humidity is at 37%in the house, and we live in Chicago if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very very common in my area as I live in a part of the Midwest that can have 60 days straight of 10-20 F in the winter and 60 days straight around 100 F in the summer.   I have bought more than a few houses with the issue before - on purpose.  Because what looks like some major structural issues going on, it is really no big deal other than the cracks in the drywall.  I know it is a big deal to you because you shouldn't have to deal with issues you didn't cause.

Why the issue just appeared had little to nothing to do with the new roof and a lot to do with the new ventilation and insulation the attic area got.  One of two things or both certainly happened:

1. The attic had a lot of loose insulation before and they got rid of a lot of this to increase ventilation.  It is very likely that your attic was full to very full of insulation before.
2. The attic did not have a great thermal barrier and they added something to create a break from the house.

There are a variety of reasons why they may have done this.  There could have been condensation/mold issues due to lack of ventilation or they could have determined that there was a considerable amount of heat loss so they wanted to redo the attic.

Most likely though the roofing company did what they usually do or made the change based on making money.  The architect/engineer that designed it originally allowed the drywall crews to nail/screw directly into the trusses at the corners.  Any architect working on a project like this would be all over this as it is a huge aesthetic thing.  It likely that the architect planned on keeping the attic "warm".  The fact is it was working just fine for a long time and someone changed it.   The roofing company should be on the hook for this period.  They probably got all kinds of money installing baffles and mushrooms and whatever, so that there was "new" insulation.

Let's talk about what is going on.  The bottom of your trusses are below insulation.  They are conditioned and dry.  They stay the same.  The top of your trusses are above the insulation.  Now that the ventilation is "better" they get even more cold air and moisture in the winter.  So they are sucking in water and elongate during cold seasons.  As they elongate they push down on the truss bottom plate on each side.  The bottom plate is stretched and bows up in the middle.  Given that your drywall was installed the same throughout your house I would guess that your biggest cracks are in the middle of the truss.  Also the vertical cracks you are getting are for the same reason - movement.  Albeit some more flexible mud and keeping your home at more consistent humidity levels would probably fix those.

[image]

Just know that seasonally your truss will pull up the highest during the winter and flatten back out during the summer.  This will just keep on happening every year with some years being worse than others.

**So how do you fix your cracks for good?**

1. Have the attic reinsulated.  Meaning less airflow and ventilation and more insulation.  If there was a ventilation related issue that they fixed there should be pictures to back it up.  You don't just change something that was working fine.  Housing systems are very unique.
2. Have all of the ceiling drywall redone.  Basically you would need to install the ceiling drywall and not attach it to the trusses anywhere within 12-20" from each wall.  This will allow the corners the ability to move with the trusses.
   My drywall guys never screw within a foot as it is but this was not common practice until the past 10-15 years.

[image]

Installing truss backing angles everywhere would fix your issue.  This is just a messy alternative but what needs to be done.

[image]

3. The last choice I offer is just to install some crown molding.  However you can't just install the crown molding using the traditional method or you will be back on here next winter asking "how do I fix a big gap at the top of my crown molding?"  What you need to do is install a wedge around the entire ceiling and attach this wedge only to the trusses.  This actually doesn't add much install time to the project as the crown molding goes up super easy and is firmly secure.  And it will move up and down with the top of the ceiling all year long.

[image]

Comment: Thanks  a lot! That makes more sense. I guess I will have to add more insulation and hope it will fix the problem.

Comment: Yours seems to be only pulling maybe 1/4-1/2".  So there is a good chance that the insulation may work.  I just don't know enough about what they did in your attic or the layout/structure of your townhouse to know for sure.  I have dealt with several houses pulling at well over an inch in parts... so it could be worse (and this isn't a "structural issue")